# Determining the latest version of a file (python)

Tags: python, file, versioning

This has me stumped...

I have a list of files in a folder. Eg.

```
myFiles = ["apple_d_v01.jpg", "apple_d_v02.jpg", "apple_d_v03.jpg", "something_d.jpg", "anotherthing_d.jpg"]
```

There are three versions of the file "apple_d", using a version suffix of "_vxx". I want to be able to modify the list to have only the latest version, so that

```
myFiles = ["apple_d_v03.jpg", "something_d.jpg", "anotherthing_d.jpg"]
```

Any ideas?

Thanks very much.

edit: came up with this thismorning- it works fine for purpose, but is a little different to the question I initially asked. Thanks all for helping out.

```
myFiles = ["apple_d.jpg", "apple_dm.jpg", "apple_d_v2.jpg", "apple_d_v3.jpg", "something_d.jpg", "anotherthing_d.jpg", "test2_s_v01", "test2_s_v02.jpg", "test2_s_v03.jpg", "test2_s_v04.jpg" ]

objVersions = []


obj = "cube"  #controlled by variable
suf = "d"     #controlled by variable
ext = ".jpg"  #controlled by variable

for file in myFiles:


    if obj + "_" + suf + "_" in file:
        objVersions.append(file)

    if obj + "_" + suf + "." in file:
        objVersions.append(file)

objVersions = sorted(objVersions, reverse=True)

for file in objVersions:

    if ext not in file:
        objVersions.remove(file)


chosenfile = objVersions[0]
```

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: I've posted a very rudimentary answer. I can improve that if you post what you've done, so that I can get a better idea of what you are looking for. `This has me stumped` What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `d` is a version number in your question

```
latestVersion = max(int(fname.rsplit('.',1)[0].rsplit("_",1)[1].strip('v')) for fname in myFiles)
```

From your comments, I understand that you want to keep the latest versions of versioned files. For that, you'll need this:

```
answer = set()
for fname in myFiles:
    name, version = fname.rsplit('.', 1)[0].rsplit("_",1)
    if version.startswith('v'): # this is a versioned file
        answer.add(
          max((fname for fname in myFiles if fname.startswith(name) and not fname.rsplit('.', 1)[0].endswith('d')), 
              key=lambda fname: int(
                     fname.rsplit('.', 1)[0].rsplit("_",1)[1].strip('v')) ))
    else:
        answer.add(fname)
```

Answer (score 0):

This Method i made i think will do what you asked,  It takes a List of file names and finds the latest version,  It then searches for all files that contain a version tag and removes the ones that are not latest.  It will not work if some files are only updated to a version 2 and others a 3.

```
def removePreviousVersions(FileNameList):
    returnList = []
    LatestVersion = 0
    for FileName in FileNameList:
        if FileName.find('_v') > -1:
            Name, Version = (FileName.replace('.jpg', '')).split('_v')
            if LatestVersion <  int(Version):
                LatestVersion = int(Version)

    argument = '_v'+ str(LatestVersion).zfill(2)
    for FileName in FileNameList:
        if FileName.find('_v') == -1:
            returnList.append(FileName)        
        elif FileName.find(argument) != -1:
            returnList.append(FileName)

    return returnList
```

This example right here works using a similar method but it will grab the latest version of a file even if it is an older version the the latest version of a file.

```
def removePreviousVersions(FileNameList):
TempFileNameList = []
ReturnList = []  
for FileName in FileNameList:
    if '_v' in FileName:
        Name, Version = (FileName.replace('.jpg', '')).split('_v')
        if Name not in TempFileNameList:
            TempFileNameList.append(Name)
            latestVersion = 0
            TempFileName = ''
            for fname in FileNameList:
                if Name in fname:
                    tName, tVersion = (fname.replace('.jpg', '')).split('_v')
                    if int(tVersion) > int(latestVersion):
                        latestVersion = int(tVersion)
                        TempFileName = fname
            ReturnList.append(TempFileName)
    else:
        ReturnList.append(FileName)

return ReturnList
```

Example Input:

NameList =  ["stupd_d_v01.jpg", "apple_d_v01.jpg", "apple_d_v02.jpg", "apple_d_v03.jpg", "something_d.jpg", "anotherthing_d.jpg"]

returns ["stupd_d_v01.jpg", "apple_d_v03.jpg", "something_d.jpg", "anotherthing_d.jpg"]

Comment: Hi Dh0rse, thanks for the input. This looks great, although there will certainly be times where there are files with more progressed versions than others. If you wouldn't mind having another quick go at a revision, I'd be very grateful

Comment: Check out my second solution,  I believe that is what you are looking for,  It is a bit slower since it is doing two for loops but it gets the info you need.

Comment: cheers Dh0rse. Will also check this out. Having a bit of a time getting the code to run..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the versions are always with the syntax of _v##, you can do this:

```
import re

parts_re = re.compile(r'^(.+_d)(.*)\.jpg$')

def remove_oldies(list):
    final = []
    saved_version = ''
    saved_name = ''
    for item in sorted(list):
        name, version = parts_re.search(item).group(1,2)
        if name != saved_name:
            if saved_name != '':
                final.append(saved_name + saved_version + ".jpg")
            saved_version = version
            saved_name = name
        else:
            saved_version = version
    final.append(saved_name + saved_version + ".jpg")
    return final

    remove_oldies(myFiles)
```

Comment: Cheers pcm- I will check this solution out.

Answer (score 0):

A short (and functional) answer would be something like:

```
files= [ (f.split("_d")[0],int("0"+re.search("((_v)?([0-9]+|))\.jpg",f.split("_d")[1]).group(3)),f) for f in myFiles]
result= [ [ f[2] for f in files if f[0] == fn and f[1] == max( [ f[1] for f in files if f[0] == fn ] ) ][0] for fn in set( f[0] for f in files ) ]
```

With a bit of expansion and comments added:

```
# List of tuples of the form ('apple', 2, 'apple_d_v02.jpg') and ('something', 0, 'something_d.jpg')
files= [ (f.split("_d")[0],int("0"+re.search("((_v)?([0-9]+|))\.jpg",f.split("_d")[1]).group(3)),f) for f in myFiles]
basename= 0  # index of basename (apple, something, etc) in each tuple inside "files"
version= 1  # index of version in each tuple inside "files"
fullname= 2  # index of full filename in each tuple inside "files"

result= [ [ f[fullname] for f in files if f[basename] == current_basename and f[version] == max( [ f[version] for f in files if f[basename] == current_basename ] ) ][0] for current_basename in set( f[basename] for f in files ) ]
```

Last line can be further expanded into:

```
def max_version_fullname(current_basename):
    versions= [ f[version] for f in files if f[basename] == current_basename ]
    max_version= max( versions )
    fullnames_for_max_version= [ f[fullname] for f in files if f[basename] == current_basename and f[version] == max_version ]
    fullname_for_max_version= fullnames_for_max_version[0]
    return fullname_for_max_version
basenames= set( f[basename] for f in files )
result= [ max_version_fullname(current_basename) for current_basename in basenames ]
```

Comment: thanks Mario - I'll look into this and try to digest your code

Answer (score -1):

this is my answer,hope to help you.:

```
 from distutils.version import LooseVersion
 files= ["apple_d.jpg", "apple_dm.jpg", "apple_d_v2.jpg", "apple_d_v3.jpg", "something_d.jpg", "anotherthing_d.jpg", "test2_s_v01", "test2_s_v02.jpg", "test2_s_v03.jpg", "test2_s_v04.jpg" ]
 listA = [f for f in files if f.startswith('apple_d')]
 listB = [f for f in files if not f.startswith('apple_d')]
 listC = [LooseVersion(f) for f in listA]
 listB.append(str(max(listC)))
 print(listB)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).